# Automating install steps kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, automation

I have a specific version of postgres with postgis that I need to use for my database. This is what I usually do to provision it:

1. Create a kubernetes secret that holds value of admin password
2. Create a PV (persistent volume) - I have .yaml for this
3. Create a PVC(pv claim) to use it for the pgdata - I have .yaml for this
4. Create deployment - I have .yaml for this
5. Create a service - I have .yaml for this

How do I automate these steps? Eventually I'd like to automate the whole app stack that we use, like a one click install. I can do it with bunch of shell scripts now, but I'm looking for a better way to do this, any good suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever looked into [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) or [Helm](https://helm.sh/)? Both are declarative ways to create reproducible deployments. IMO Terraform is more for the basic Kubernetes infrastructure itself, while I see Helm more used for Kubernetes applications running on this infrastructure.

Since you're starting from scratch you could also look at tools like [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/) which allows you to code your infrastructure. This might come handy when doing complex migrations, which would require multiple Terraform/Helm charts and additional scripts exectuted in a certain order, whereas a migration could also be done in one Pulumi exection.

For completeness I am adding [NAML](https://github.com/kris-nova/naml) which is an open source tool I recently came accross.